# Analysing count data for biodiversity

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, diversity

So I'm confused about how to analyze some data for a biodiversity survey I'm undertaking. Incidences of birds are recorded at 25 stations on four sites (so 100 points in total). My response variable is count data and my explanatory variables are the different land-uses at each site (three different types of woodland, and one farm-field). Are Generalized Linear Models (GLMs) a good idea?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This site can provide useful tips on selecting the models and interpreting their output. Other reasons will provide specific instructions on implementing the models, such as in R. Can you say a bit more about how birds are "counted"? Is this a catch-release program? Special methods are needed for that case to account for the possibility of catching the same bird twice.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks! I'll be doing point-counts, so at 25 pre-determined points I will stand and record all the incidences of birds that I can see and hear, in two band classes (0-50m, 50m+). The points are spaced 200m apart to reduce the probability of double-counting birds.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the data, but a generalized linear model will probably work well for your data - you can specify the "poisson" family to model count data.  You might want to do a generalized linear mixed effects model, as it sounds like "site" is a random effect within your study.

If you were using R you could use the "lme4" package and try the following:

```
library(lme4)
my_model <- glmer(counts ~ land_use + (1|site), family="poisson")
```